# How to use a button to change the styles of other buttons?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, button, addeventlistener

So I want to have a dynamic image gallery.  When you click on the landscapes buttons, the other highlighted button changes it's style to default while the landscapes button I clicked changes to the clicked style.  I want each button I click to reset any button that is clicked to default and changing the button I clicked to the new clicked style.

I am trying to use event listeners with functions for each button thats clicked to reset and set styles.

Structures is the default button to be in its clicked state.  So I set it's styles in the css.  But when I click on the abstract button, it's supposed to change the structured button to the default style and itself to the click style, why isn't it changing?

```
html 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="painting-buttons">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="buttons">
                <button id="structures" 
                        class="button-solid black-button" onclick="location.href='#'" 
                        type="button">
                        Structures
                </button>
                <button id="abstract" 
                        class="button-solid black-button" 
                        onclick="location.href='#'" 
                        type="button">
                        Abstract
                </button>
                <button id="oil" 
                        class="button-solid black-button" 
                        onclick="location.href='#'" 
                        type="button">
                        Oil
                </button>
                <button id="landscapes" 
                        class="button-solid black-button" 
                        onclick="location.href='#'" 
                        type="button">
                        Landscapes
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
css

.button-solid {
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 12px 40px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
    border-radius: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
}

.button-solid:hover {
    background: #31aece;
    border-color: #31aece;
    color: #fff;
    transition: background 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button-transparent {
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 6px 30px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
    border-radius: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
}

.button-transparent a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #DB170D;
    transition: background 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*-- -------------------------- -->
<---         PAINTINGS          -->
<--- -------------------------- -*/

#painting-buttons {
    height: auto;
}

.buttons button {
    width: 45%;
    padding: 10px 20px !important;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.buttons {
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* Default Button Focus */
#structures {
    color: #fff;
    background: #31AECE;
    border: none;
}
```

```
javascript

/* Button click events for the paintings, etchings, and sculptures pages */

/* Button varibale assignment */
var structures = document.getElementById("structures");
var abstract = document.getElementById("abstract");
var oil = document.getElementById("oil");
var landscapes = document.getElementById("landscapes");

/*Button Gets Clicked */
structures.addEventListener("click", function(clickStructures));
abstract.addEventListener("click", function(clickAbstract));

function clickStructures() {
    /*Structures Button Clicked Style */
    structures.style.background = "#31AECE";
    structures.style.color = "#fff";
    structures.style.border = "none";

    /* Reset Abstract Button */
    abstract.style.background = "transparent";
    abstract.style.color = "#000";
    abstract.style.border = "#000";

    /* Reset Oil Button */
    oil.style.background = "transparent";
    oil.style.color = "#000";
    oil.style.border = "#000";

    /* Reset Landscape Button */
    landscape.style.background = "transparent";
    landscape.style.color = "#000";
    landscape.style.border = "#000";
}

function clickAbstract() {
    /*Abstract Button Clicked Style */
    abstract.style.background = "#31AECE";
    abstract.style.color = "#fff";
    abstract.style.border = "none";

    /* Reset Structures Button */
    structures.style.background = "transparent";
    structures.style.color = "#000";
    structures.style.border = "#000";

    /* Reset Oil Button */
    oil.style.background = "transparent";
    oil.style.color = "#000";
    oil.style.border = "#000";

    /* Reset Landscape Button */
    landscape.style.background = "transparent";
    landscape.style.color = "#000";
    landscape.style.border = "#000";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with the pseudoclass ":focus" in your ccs styles?
Example:

```
         .button:focus{
                        color: green;
                }
```

Comment: yes, but when the page loads I want "structures" to already be focused. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: and the problem is when you click anywhere else on the screen the button isnt focused anymore

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually your working with a toggle state. So you should be able to reduce it to toggle on and off.

You can wrap the two styles into two classes (shortform).

```
`.on{background:#31AECE;
 .off{backround:transparent;`
```

Then you need to move your elements to an array.

```
'var structures = document.getElementById("structures");
 var abstract = document.getElementById("abstract");
 var oil = document.getElementById("oil");
 var landscapes = document.getElementById("landscapes");'


 var butts = [oil, structures, abstract, etc];
```

And add a coloring event

```
for(var i = 0; i < butts.length; i += 1){
buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.target.toggleClass('on');
});
```

}

all you need is to tell all the buttons not in the click event to toggle their
states

buttons.toggleClass('off');

Comment: so the "off" class would be already on the buttons, and the "on" class get's toggled on and off?